# PARIでは「ある条件式を満たす要素だけ取り出すようなメソッド」はありますか？

Tags: ruby, pari

Ruby の

```
p (1..100).select{|i| i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0}
```

のようなプログラムをPARIで書きたいと思っています。
すなわちある条件式を満たす要素だけ取り出すようなプログラムを書きたいのですがどうすればいいですか？
P.S.
select のオーバーフローする範囲にびっくりしたので追加の質問をします。
簡単な質問で申し訳ないのですが、

```
(1..10 ** 10).each{|i| p i if i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0}
```

のプログラムはPARIではどう書けばいいでしょうか？

Comment: PARI/GP v2.4.9 だと `select(i -> i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0, [1..100])` ですかね。

Comment: ＠metropolis できました。ありがとうございます。PARI でもselect が使えるようですね。しかし、すぐオーバーフローしてしまいますね。

Comment: スタックサイズ(`parisize`)を増やしてもオーバーフローしてしまいますね… それでは for loop を使って `for(i=1,10^10,if(i%3==0||i%5==0,print(i)))`  ですかね。

Comment: ＠metropolis ありがとうございます。for loop の方がいいですね。